# Compare 2 strings in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, string, nsstring, comparison

I wrote the following code:

```
   if (depSelectedIndice > -1 && comSelectedIndice> -1)
        {
            NSLog(@"depart elemet : %d ",depSelectedIndice);
            NSLog(@"depart elemet : %d ",comSelectedIndice);
            NSLog(@"ok1");
            NSString *choosedDate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[deparatureDates objectAtIndex:depSelecif (depSelectedIndice > -1 && comSelectedIndice> -1)
    {
        NSLog(@"depart elemet : %d ",depSelectedIndice);
        NSLog(@"depart elemet : %d ",comSelectedIndice);
        NSLog(@"ok1");
        NSString *choosedDate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[deparatureDates objectAtIndex:depSelectedIndice], [goingBackDates objectAtIndex:comSelectedIndice]];
        NSLog(@"0000000000001");

        NSLog(@" number of element : %d", [allCombinations count]);
//        for (int j=0; j<[allCombinations count]; j++)
//        {
//            NSLog(@"111111111111111111");
//           // NSString *date = [[allCombinations objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"keydate"];
//            NSLog(@"22222222222222222222");
//              if([date isEqualToString:choosedDate])
//              {
//                  depPrice.text=@"1";
//                  comPrice.text=@"1";
//                  price.text=@"3";
//                  
//              }
       // }
    }
```

allCombinations is an `NSArray` declared in .h, I have initilase and used it in another method. I can't use in in this method? :/

But I have a crash. I don't really know where the problem is but I think it's when I compare `if(date==choosedDate)`? Help please

Comment: Can you add your stack trace when the crash occurs?

Comment: @dredful @dredful @Chris Thank you all . i edited my post . The problem come from allCombinations . I have 0000000000001 in the consol.The crach is when i make [allCombinations count] .There are no error in the consol to post it here :( help pleeease

Comment: "allCombinations is an NSArray declared in .h , I have initilase and use it in another method . I can't use in in this method ? :/" - You will have to show us the code/methods that relate to `allCombinations` so we can see if you are doing something incorrect with it.

Answer (score 26):

When you use an `==` on pointers like `NSString *` it is comparing memory addresses, not comparing the value of strings.

The following will actually compare the string values:

```
if([date isEqualToString:choosedDate])
```

Answer (score 3):

In Objective C better way to compare two string is:

```
NSString *string1 = <your string>;
NSString *string2 = <your string>;

if ([string1 caseInsensitiveCompare:string2] == NSOrderedSame) {
    //strings are same
} else {
    //strings are not same
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using `[date isEqualToString:choosedDate]` instead of `date==choosedDate`, my initial reaction would be to make sure that `depSelectedIndice` and `comSelectedIndice` do not refer to elements past the end of `deparatureDates` and `goingBackDates` in the following line.

```
NSString *choosedDate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[deparatureDates objectAtIndex:depSelectedIndice], [goingBackDates objectAtIndex:comSelectedIndice]];
```

I don't whether `depPrice`, `comPrice`, and `price` were allocated correctly, nor what their types are, but they could be causing you problems, as well.